# Alert box not closing

Tags: javascript

Please help with this div alert box...It doesn't close on click event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.nof-close').click(function(){
            $('.afp-p-now').fadeOut();
            $('.afp-p-now').css('display','none');

        }); 

    }); 
    </script>

<div class="flash-messages container afp-p-now">
        <div class="flash flash-notice">Welcome to website...You are currently viewing me  
        <span class="mini-icon mini-icon-remove-close nof-close close"></span>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Any Idea will be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I dont see an alert box in that code.

Comment: @Rob I think OP is calling his `div` an alert box...

Comment: Are you getting any error? Have even added the jQuery script to your web page? A little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) may be a good option. Your code seems fine.

Comment: @Kindo: What errors do you get? Is the click event properly executed? Do you have included the jQuery library?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/Qwq4z/1/ -> check this fiddle.

Comment: Yeap! Jquery library is done just not working

Comment: this does work. [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xAGz7/). You don't need to set css again after applying `fadeOut`

Comment: Thanks Guys but still no avail

Comment: jQuery not included? Add this line in your <head>: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because there is nothing to click on, the span has no content.
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.nof-close').click(function(){
        $('.afp-p-now').fadeOut();        
    });    
});
</script>
<div class="flash-messages container afp-p-now">
     <div class="flash flash-notice">Welcome to website...You are currently viewing me  
         <span class="mini-icon mini-icon-remove-close nof-close close">[Click here to close]</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

You could also change the span into a button (`<button class="mini-icon mini-icon-remove-close nof-close close">Close</button>`) .